# ParseInt does not convert from String to Int in React Native

Tags: react-native, rest, expo

I am trying to call an endpoint from Flutterwave inside React native application. And it gives me this challenge as I try to initiate a POST request as I have entered all the information correctly into the application.

This is the error i am getting

[image: Screenshot-1679041423.png]

Where 54000 is the amount entered

and i have the amount in the UI as shown above

My code is looking thus

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

const SATransferExample = () => {
    const [account_bank, setAccountBank] = useState('');
    const [beneficiary_name, setBeneficiaryName] = useState('');
    const [account_number, setAccountNumber] = useState('');
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
    const [narration, setNarration] = useState('');
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('');
    const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [last_name, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [mobile_number, setMobileNumber] = useState('');
    const [recipient_address, setRecipientAddress] = useState('');

    InitiateTransfers = () => {
        //Alert.alert('Test');
        var amount_int = parseInt(amount, 10);

        let item = {
            account_bank,
            beneficiary_name,
            account_number,
            amount_int,
            narration,
            currency,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            email,
            mobile_number,
            recipient_address,
        };

        fetch('https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(item),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                if (responseJson.message === 'Transfer Queued Successfully') {
                    /*localStorage.setItem('userinfo', username);
                history.push('/dashboard');*/
                    Alert.alert('Transfer Complete');
                } else {
                    alert(responseJson.message);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.space2} />
            <ScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                }}
            >
                <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }} />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Account Bank"
                    value={account_bank}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setAccountBank({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Beneficiary Name"
                    value={beneficiary_name}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setBeneficiaryName({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Account Number"
                    value={account_number}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setAccountNumber({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Amount"
                    value={parseInt(amount)}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setAmount({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Narration"
                    value={narration}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setNarration({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Currency"
                    value={currency}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setCurrency({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" First Name"
                    value={first_name}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setFirstName({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Last Name"
                    value={last_name}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setLastName({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setEmail({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Mobile Number"
                    value={mobile_number}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setMobileNumber({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder=" Receipient Address"
                    value={recipient_address}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setRecipientAddress({ text })}
                    style={styles.input}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.InitiateTransfers();
                    }}
                    style={styles.button}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Submit </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

export default SATransferExample;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },

    input: {
        width: 300,
        height: 55,
        margin: 5,
        fontSize: 19,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        borderBottomColor: '#030303',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 30,
    },

    button: {
        width: 300,
        height: 52,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#030303',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: 50,
    },

    Regbutton: {
        width: 300,
        height: 52,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#030303',
    },

    loginbtn: {
        color: '#ffff',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },

    AccountBalance: {
        fontSize: 13,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'left',
    },

    loginbtn2: {
        color: '#030303',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },

    logo: {
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
    },

    space: {
        width: 10,
        height: 20,
    },

    space2: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
    },

    imageStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 5,
        margin: 2,
        height: 15,
        width: 15,
        resizeMode: 'stretch',
        marginBottom: 8,
        marginTop: 8,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});
```

Calling it from App.js

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import SATransferExample from './src/SATransferExample';

const App = () => {
    return <SATransferExample />;
};

export default App;
```

The problem is, why is it telling me that amount is required, and I have entered amount earlier. Even after converting to numbers (int) it sill gives error.

**Edit**

After adding and removing all requested, it prompts a new Error

[image: Screenshot-1679043832.png]

testing from Postman

[image: res.png]

Now this is what my code looks like

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Alert } from "react-native";

const SATransferExample = () => {
  const [account_bank, setAccountBank] = useState("");
  const [beneficiary_name, setBeneficiaryName] = useState("");
  const [account_number, setAccountNumber] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const [narration, setNarration] = useState("");
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("");
  const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [last_name, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [mobile_number, setMobileNumber] = useState("");
  const [recipient_address, setRecipientAddress] = useState("");

  InitiateTransfers = () => {
    //Alert.alert('Test');
    //var amount_int = parseInt(amount,10);

    let item = {
      account_bank,
      beneficiary_name,
      account_number,
      amount,
      narration,
      currency,
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      mobile_number,
      recipient_address,
    };

    fetch("https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if (responseJson.message === "Transfer Queued Successfully") {
          /*localStorage.setItem('userinfo', username);
            history.push('/dashboard');*/
          Alert.alert("Transfer Complete");
        } else {
          alert(responseJson.message);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.space2} />
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }} />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Account Bank"
          value={account_bank}
          onChangeText={(text) => setAccountBank(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Beneficiary Name"
          value={beneficiary_name}
          onChangeText={(text) => setBeneficiaryName(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Account Number"
          value={account_number}
          onChangeText={(text) => setAccountNumber(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Amount"
          value={parseInt(amount)}
          onChangeText={(text) => setAmount(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Narration"
          value={narration}
          onChangeText={(text) => setNarration(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Currency"
          value={currency}
          onChangeText={(text) => setCurrency(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" First Name"
          value={first_name}
          onChangeText={(text) => setFirstName(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Last Name"
          value={last_name}
          onChangeText={(text) => setLastName(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Mobile Number"
          value={mobile_number}
          onChangeText={(text) => setMobileNumber(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Receipient Address"
          value={recipient_address}
          onChangeText={(text) => setRecipientAddress(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.InitiateTransfers();
          }}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Submit </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SATransferExample;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },

  input: {
    width: 300,
    height: 55,
    margin: 5,
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    borderBottomColor: "#030303",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },

  button: {
    width: 300,
    height: 52,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#030303",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 50,
  },

  Regbutton: {
    width: 300,
    height: 52,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#030303",
  },

  loginbtn: {
    color: "#ffff",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

  AccountBalance: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "left",
  },

  loginbtn2: {
    color: "#030303",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

  logo: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },

  space: {
    width: 10,
    height: 20,
  },

  space2: {
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
  },

  imageStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 5,
    margin: 2,
    height: 15,
    width: 15,
    resizeMode: "stretch",
    marginBottom: 8,
    marginTop: 8,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: Hard to say with the given information, but your screen shot looks like on your phone/simulator you didn't execute the latest code, because the connection got lost. ("Cannot connect to Metro")

Comment: Assuming that `parseInt` wouldn't work is quite a bold assumption. I'd rather assume you are not using it correctly. For instance you are initializing `const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");` with an empty string and then do `var amount_int = parseInt(amount,10);` first thing in your component. At this point `amount` is still an empty string, what number would that parse to? And also `onChangeText={(text) => setAmount({ text })}` seems a bit strange to me, shouldn't that be `onChangeText={(text) => setAmount(text)}` (and same for all other change handlers)

Comment: Together with `value={parseInt(amount)}` after a rerender (caused by altering the state), it will of course set that input empty again, because `parseInt` cannot parse the object `{ text }` you are assigning to the `amount` property ...

Comment: @derpirscher i have removed that part now it returns a new Error , i am updating

Comment: Well, the object you are sending does not have a `meta` property and seemingly the API requires it ... Ie, you have to put your `firstname`, `lastname`... inside a `meta` object like in the postman request, that seems to be working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `text` from the `onChangeText` handler to the states in a object `{}`.

```js
onChangeText={(text) => setAmount({ text })}

// will result in
// amount = { text: 'your text' }
```

You can simply use

```js
onChangeText={(text) => setAmount(text)}
```

This is the same for all the other inputs.

---

You should add `const` to your `InitiateTransfers` function.

```js
const InitiateTransfers = () => {
  ...
};
```

You're using `this` in a functional component which seems a bit weird.

```js
onPress={() => {
  this.InitiateTransfers();
}}
```

Should be something like

```js
onPress={() => {
  InitiateTransfers();
}}
```

---

For the meta required you can update the `item` variable by adding the `meta` prop and passing the values

```js
let item = {
    account_bank,
    beneficiary_name,
    account_number,
    amount,
    narration,
    currency,
    meta: {
        first_name,
        last_name,
        email,
        mobile_number,
        recipient_address,
    },
};
```

Comment: Pls see edits. I updated as you said, it gave a new error